# Raspberry pi boot error: No working init found

Tags: boot, parrot

When I try to run parrot os on my raspberry pi I get a boot error saying `---[end kernel panic - not syncing : No working unit found. Try passing in init= option to kernel. Sell Linux documentation/init.txt for guidance`

The sd card I have installed parrot os on is brand new, I am also a noob and may be doing something stupid.

The raspberry pi boots fine with my other micro sd card running noobs.

[image: image of boot.]

My `/boot/cmdline.txt` refers to `root=/dev/mmcblk0p2`.

Comment: Edit in your `/boot/cmdline.txt`.

Comment: @goldilocks what do I edit

Comment: "Edit in", as in, cut and paste into the question above.  It should be on the first partition of the card, which is the only one readable on any computer (because it is vfat formatted).  It will be all one line.

Comment: @goldilocks I am sorry that I don't understand but I have opened my sd card in file explorer on windows and see all of the files. I see a cmdline text document and a configure document, what should I do.

Comment: It's the one named `cmdline.txt`.  It is not very long.  What's relevant here is the `root=` field there.  There is an "edit" button on the interface above that you can edit your question with.

Comment: @goldilocks I am in the cmdline.txt and the only part that starts with root = is a part that says root=/dev/mmcblk0p2

Comment: Well, that's most likely correct -- although I recommend you try a less obscure distro if you are new to this (almost certainly anything that's available/installed in Parrot can be installed in Raspbian).  The error you have above is that [init](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init) can't be found, and a common reason for this is it is looking in a non-existent/corrupt/etc. partition (init is a program stored on the second partition).  Inspecting the card really requires another linux system, or at least something which can read `ext4` filesystems.

Comment: @goldilocks I do have a ubuntu virtual machine, do you think that would work

Comment: Yes.  You just have to look at the second partition and see if it looks like a normal GNU/Linux root fs (particularly, whether there is an `/sbin/init` file there).

Comment: @goldilocks ok I will do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug with the current release (3.8) of parrot OS. The second, ext4 partition is completely empty, hence the init not being found. Hopefully it gets fixed soon, but until then this thread should help.

https://community.parrotsec.org/viewtopic.php?id=930